# Programmatically show pattern screen lock

Tags: android, wakelock, power-management, keyguard, screen-lock

I wrote an android app (with system privileges and Admin permission is granted).

In my application, at first time in the device, I am setting programmatically a new pattern screen lock, then running some things and then I want to close my app and to make the pattern screen lock re-appear so the user will have to verify it before continuing to use his device.

I couldn’t find another way to do that except for locking the device + waking it immediately, so my code looks something like this:

```
mLockPatternUtils.saveLockPattern(pattern);
mLockPatternUtils.setLockPatternEnabled(true);
mLockPatternUtilssetVisiblePatternEnabled(true);

//run some things


DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
devicePolicyManager.lockNow();

WakeLock w = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");
w.acquire();
```

But it doesn’t seem to work! The pattern screen lock is not showing. My guess is that setting the pattern when none was previously set is causing it – I just don’t know how to solve it.

By the way - doing this after a screen lock existing in the device – works fine...

Any advise??

Thanx!